# Smart TV development: compression size

Tags: compression, size, samsung-smart-tv

After completing the application, you have situations where you need to change things in your code. If you edit it directly from the zip file and just update it; how important is to update the compression size of widgetlist.xml? 
I have seen that it works even if is not the exact byte size, but can this be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

It is not a strict problem, yet there is a check for the zip size and the size tag in widgetlist.xml. My guess is that there is a range of tolerance for which the two can differ. At the moment it does not block application installation, it would be safer to have them match just in case this check becomes strict in the future.

Comment: I've edited the package (adding videos) and re-zipped without changing the compression size. I seems the downloaded package still using the size on widgetlist.xml and the application cannot start. So, I agree with "tolerance" since minor modification doesn't causing problem

Answer (score 1):

Samsung Smart Hub uses compression size for check: Does TV has a free storage memory to download and install application.

```
if (compression size > free space * 2 * some value) hub will not download app.
```

I use (free space * 2 *  some value) because hub first downloads app in temp directory and then unpackages it. When you developing applications and have enough free space on your device - you can set 0 or other not absolutely true size as 'compression size' attribute but in production version please use true size value.

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with size in widgetlist.xml. You can have size 100000 or 123 and it works fine.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rsp stat="ok">
<list>
<widget id="myappid">
<title>myapp</title>
<compression size="100" type="zip"/>
<description/>
<download>http://192.168.27.181/Widget/app.zip</download>
</widget>
</list>
</rsp>



<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<rsp stat="ok">
<list>
<widget id="myappid">
<title>myapp</title>
<compression size="1000000" type="zip"/>
<description/>
<download>http://192.168.27.181/Widget/app.zip</download>
</widget>
</list>
</rsp>
```

M.